# How to test my update action with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

In my Rails application I have this **update** action:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authorized_user

  def update
    current_email = @user.email
    new_email = params[:user][:email].downcase.to_s
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])    
      if new_email != current_email
        @user.change_email(current_email, new_email)     
        flash[:success] = "Please click on the link that we've sent you."
      else
        flash[:success] = "User updated."
      end
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def authorized_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
  end

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def change_email(old_email, new_email)
    self.email = old_email
    self.new_email = new_email.downcase    
    self.send_email_confirmation_link  
  end

end
```

Now, everything works perfectly when I test the **update** action manually in the browser.

The **RSpec** test that I wrote, however, does not work and I can't figure out why:

```
it "changes @user's new_email" do
  @user = create(:user, email: "john@doe.com")
  put :update, id: @user, user: attributes_for(:user, email: "new@email.com")
  @user.reload
  expect(@user.new_email).to eq("new@email.com")
end
```

I keep getting the same error message:

> 1) UsersController user access PUT #update with valid attributes changes @user's new_email
>        Failure/Error: expect(@user.new_email).to eq("new@email.com")

```
   expected: "new@email.com"
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: which are your user fields in DB?

Comment: `email`, `new_email` and others

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo

```
expect(@user.email).to eq("new@email.com")
```

You are not saving user in `change_email`, and you are updating `email` in your controller. So `new_email` is not updated in your code.

To save your record use

```
def change_email(old_email, new_email)
  self.email = old_email
  self.new_email = new_email.downcase 
  save
  self.send_email_confirmation_link  
end
```

## Callback

Could be something like this:

```
# controller
if @user.update_attributes[:user]
  redirect_to somewhere
else
  render :edit

# model
after_update :change_email
```

But there are more changes than these, this is just a schema.

anyway, maybe you should use a callback in your model instead of writing more code in your controller.

Comment: No, it's not a typo. The intention is to save to the `new_email` database field. The user will then have to *confirm* his new email address through a link.

Comment: No, the `save` doesn't seem to change anything either. The `new_email` gets saved to the database (I can see it there), but my test still won't pass. Maybe I am taking the wrong approach here. I simply want that users have to confirm their email address if they ever change it. What would such a `callback` look like? It should ideally be triggered on `update` only.

Comment: Try this `put :update, id: @user.id, user: {email: "new@email.com"}`

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your controller.

Firstly, you have not defined `@user` at all. That's the reason your result is nil

```
# Define it
@user = User.find(params[:id]) # if your url is POST /user/1/update
```

Secondly, better not to use `email` only, what if in the further you want to allow users to edit other attributes say birthday etc?

Thirdly, updating user attributes is a bit tricky than others, the user must have authority to do that. Considering one user manipulate the form attributes in browser and post to another user's `update`, what will happen?

So you must check if the user can do that.

Combining together:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user != current_user
    return redirect_to(:back, alert: "not allowed to edit")
  end

  attrs = params[:user]

  if @user.update_attributes attrs
     //do something
  else
     render { action 'edit' }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for not making that clear in my initial post. I updated above how my `@user` is defined. My intention was just to keep the code simple.